# how to print the text of the selected item in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to something very simple. I have this select tag

```
<select id="appID">
<option value="1409608204102">test app 1</option>
<option value="1409608295422">test set 2</option>                       </select>
```

I want to print the text of the selected option in the "printHere" div. Very simple but for some reason I cant figure out how to do it through jquery

I am doing this but

```
$('#appID').change(function(){
               var k = $(this).is('selected','selected').text();
               $('.printHere').text(k);
           });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
var k = $(':selected', this).text();
```

`k` will be `"test app 1"` or `"test set 2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:selected`,

```
var k = $(this).find(':selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding what the other posters have said into a working example for you. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kshreve/P6qbp/2/

```
var k = $(this).find(':selected').text();
$("div").text(k);
```